# Why does ArcGIS Resample tool change cell size and numbers of columns and rows?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, digital-image-processing

I am working with images of oxygen distribution within individual plant root systems submerged in water. The program I use to acquire these images, LookatRGB, splits the green band in half and makes two green rasters. However, in this process, it changes the cell size to (1.4580744, 325.25). When I use the resample tool in ArcMap, the rows and columns change from the correct number of 1953, 1301 to an incorrect number of 1953, 290212. I have tried changing everything in the environment setting to the correct numbers and projecting to a UTM coordinate system, with no results. As of now, the only way I have been able to fix the problem is by changing the properties in Imagej, then exporting as a tiff. I used this corrected layer in the environment settings, but I need to be able to process thousands of images in the future using ArcMap's model builder/python. Fixing individually in ImageJ then importing into ArcMap will not work.

Comment: (325.25 * 1301) / 1.4580744 = 290212  (cells are square in ArcGIS)

Comment: A raster can have rectangular cells in ArcGIS but Spatial Analyst works with square cells only, so output will have square cells.

Comment: Thank you for the input, however when I put the rectangular cells into raster calculator I still get a rectangular cell output.

Comment: If you right-click on the layer and go to Properties, what are the number of rows and columns reported?  Are you relying on a visual interpretation of rectangular cells or the actual number of rows and columns?

Comment: In the properties of the resampled image there are 1953 rows and 290212 columns. In the properties of the original image there are 1953 rows and 1301 columns but the pixel size is (1.4580744, 325.25) so both forms are unusable.

Comment: The issue is clearly with the LookatRGB, which is apparently writing incorrect x y cell size metadata to your raster. A batch workflow would depend on what image format LookatRGB is producing.